# Chrome value on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have some problems with the browser Chrome, when it remembers password, username, etc. I cannot check if the input field is empty. 
I use the following code, but the *if* statement doesn't work in Chrome while it works in all other browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.inputWithLabel').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length != 0){
            var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('label[for="' + element_id + '"]').addClass('inputWithText');
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to alter the following labels

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="username">Brugernavn*</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="username" name="username" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="password">Adgangskode*</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="password" name="password" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="password_again">Gentag adgangskode*</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="password_again" name="password_again" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="first_name">Fornavn*</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="last_name">Efternavn</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <label class="labelInput" for="email">Email*</label>
        <input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="email" name="email" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="divInputLabel inputLabel">
        <input type="Submit" class="submit-button" value="Registre">
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Where in the document is this script included?

Comment: I've tried just after <html> and before the </html> none of it works.

Comment: Well it's not empty if it's prefilled by the browser. What is intended behavior? When page is loaded - do you want to reset all the fields?

Comment: I want to add a class for the label to change layout. The layout will be different, when label is not empty. When I remove the if statement, the function works fine, but all input fields get changed. I just don’t understand why the if statement won’t work in Chrome, but works in all other browsers.

Comment: Show your markup as well so we can see the structure you're trying to alter.

Comment: May be Chrome insert saved user data after some time after load document. Try use timeout to check fields.

Comment: I believe Chrome fires `change` event when prefilling form elements. You can try capturing it once to reset the values

Comment: Yuriy Galanter is right, I added this
$('.inputWithLabel').change(
    function(){
        var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('label[for="' + element_id + '"]').addClass('inputWithText');
    });
which works in Chrome.

Comment: Does these text fields have value when page loads??

Answer (score 1):

To check and see if the input is empty or not you can do something simpler like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inputWithLabel").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == "") {
            alert("Input is null!");
        } else {
            alert("Input is valid");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your code, apply this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.inputWithLabel').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length != 0 && $(this).val().length != null){
            var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('label[for="' + element_id + '"]').addClass('inputWithText');
        }
    });
});
```

Only set `&& $(this).val().length != null` after `$(this).val().length != 0` and it should run on different browsers. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body .inputWithLabel').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length != 0){
          var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
          $('label[for="' + element_id + '"]').addClass('inputWithText');
        }
      });
   });
```

Just append body i.e `$('body .inputWithLabel')` in your each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code looks fine... 
Label does not have .val() .. if we want innertext of label it should be .text()
so replace `.val()` with `.text()` and it will work hopefully....
Also first append body i.e
    `$('body .inputWithLabel')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.inputWithLabel').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('label[for="' + element_id + '"]').addClass('inputWithText');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it in your site

```
$('.inputWithLabel').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== null && $(this).val() !== "") {
        var element_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + element_id).removeClass('inputWithLabel').addClass('inputWithText');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried a similar thing. All you have to do is first turn your form id into a jQuery variable,

```
var $elem = document.getElementById("yourformid").value; //make sure your id has no # symbol
if ($elem > 0) {
    //do stuff
}
```

that should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no possibility to detect if the form is filled by the browser autocompletion. Some alternatives I would suggest are:

Disable autocomplete: If you dont need it, this would be an easy solution

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

or on the whole form:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Using the change event to detect any change on the field:

```
$('#username').on('change keyup',function(){
    // to something
});
```

Here I can imagine to set a class if there is any change on the input field like:

```
$('#username').on('change keyup',function(){
    $(this).addClass('changed');
});
```

Or change the name attribute on the submitted field. e.g.: use this as default:

```
<input class="inputLabel inputWithLabel" id="username" name="usernameAutofill" type="text">
```

and change it later to this if anything is done with the input:

```
$('#username').on('change keyup',function(){
    $(this).attr('name', 'username');
});
```

**But before you do any of this ask yourself following questions:**
Why you want to proof the Fields?
What should happen if they are autofilled?
What should happen if they are empty?
What should happen if they are regulary filled?

*Because what solution is the best depends pretty much on what exactly you want to do.* If you answer this question we can help you more.

Answer (score -2):

try using:

```
$('').value
```

or

```
this.value
```

or

```
this.textContent
```

or

```
$('').innerHTML
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is checking each input element which HAS some value, not the ones which are empty.
Try changing your condition to:

```
if ($(this).val().length == 0){
...
```

this would add the class to the empty field label(s).